# Particle Emitter libgdx Java

Tags: java, libgdx

I can't find any help whatsoever while looking up what the `ParticleEmitter` object can be used for. Methods such as `addParticle` have no documentation and I have no idea what it does.

I want to use a particle emmiter object to hopefully gain more control over my particles.

Can anyone help me in figuring out what the `ParticleEmitter` object can be used for?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the source. All the public methods have relatively straightforward names that make sense if you're used to working with the [particle editor](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Particle-Editor).

For example, at the risk of sounding obvious, the `addParticle()` method adds a particle to the system whereas `addParticles(int count)` adds `count` number of particles to the system.

However, seeing as the particle editor lets you do pretty much everything, are you sure you need to deal with the ParticleEmitter directly? Do you have any specific things you'd like to achieve that can't be done using that?

Comment: yes I want multiple particles drawn with one emitter without controlling multiple particles by object name or without a particle stage

Comment: Also what is this addParticle() do exactly? It doesn't take a particle object or anything so that confuses me

Comment: You configure the ParticleEmitter with the sort of particles you want, then you call addParticle to have it create particles and add them to the system. Looking at the source is the best way to work out how it all works tbh.